# Sending Data containing HTML Page to webMethod using C#

Tags: ajax, webmethod

I need to save the html file in one of the folder of my project. For which 
Using jquery i got the complete html of the page ( var content=$("#pageContent").html())  in a variable . I need to send this html content to the Web Method using ajax call to save at a location. For that i m using

> $.ajax({ url:'getpage.asmx/getpage', type:'POST', data:{data:content},
>   success:{function(res){}}, error:{function (er){}} });

Performing above approach i'm getting internal server error, and i"m not sure whether we can send string having html tags to web methods or not.
Need some way to per

Answer (score 0):

i see in your question:

> Performing above approach i'm getting ***internal server error***

I do not work with C#, but it means that you have a problems when you received the post inside your C#.
Maybe because of syntax error or something like that.

I used to have this error when I perform an AJAX request to an API, in PHP because I forgot a ';' after a var for example.

You may look into your C# script and try to figured out what is wrong.
if you do not have syntax error, or something,
try to send a string without html, and see if your script work.

if it does, try to encode your content:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'getpage.asmx/getpage',
    //encode your content
    type:'POST', data:{ data: encodeURIComponent(content) },
    //text || json to set what type you will get from your C# script
    datatype: 'text',
    //callback if success res will be a text in this case
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    //callback if error er will be a text in this case
    error: function(er) {
        console.log(er);
    }
});
```

i have removed `success:`**{**`function(res){}`**}**`,` in error too, it is not necessary

if your script work with this, you can stock the html content like this,
and when you need it you can `decodeURIComponent();` in your javascript before append.

***Documentations:***

`encodeURIComponent();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

`decodeURIComponent();`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: I have tried to overcome this issue by replacing all the html tags with some kind of special charecters and sent it to the server side . Whereas at server side again rechange those special charecters to the html tags and it works fine.Its the html tags which is creating issue to transfer that to server side. And finally wirtten server code to save at project filder.